# Calling an executable from java code

Tags: java, exe

I am trying to run an executable with its argument from java code. In console when I wish to run my exe I write: `>colorDescriptor 1.jpg --detector densesampling --ds_spacing 6 --ds_scales 1.2 --descriptor opponentsift --codebook CODEBOOK --output output.descr`. When I tried to run that executable from java I am using the following code:

```
    String[] cmd = { "colorDescriptor.exe" , "1.jpg", " --detector densesampling --ds_spacing 6 --ds_scales 1.2 --descriptor opponentsift --codebook CODEBOOK  ", "  --output output.descr"};
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);        
    waitF(process);
```

However it seems not to work properly, I got the following issue: `Warning: no output file to write to. Did you forget to specify --output?` Am I doing something wrongly when I call .exe?

Comment: Use ProcessBuilder. Deal with streams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every argument should be a separate String in String[] cmd;
e.g.:

```
String[] cmd = { "colorDescriptor.exe" , "1.jpg", "--detector", "densesampling", "--ds_spacing", "6", "--ds_scales", "1.2", "--descriptor", "opponentsift", "--codebook", "CODEBOOK", "--output", "output.descr"};
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide command either as single string or string array containing several strings and then Wrap within try-catch block, as exec(...) throws exception

```
Throws:
SecurityException - If a security manager exists and its checkExec method doesn't allow creation of the subprocess
IOException - If an I/O error occurs
NullPointerException - If command is null
IllegalArgumentException - If command is empty
```